# Which is correct 'Thanks are due' or 'Thanks is due'?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

What is the correct usage, 'Thanks are due' or 'Thanks is due' and why? Does it have to do with singular or plural?

Comment: If common sense doesn't do it for you, you could just check out [actual usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Thanks+are+due%2CThanks+is+due&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CThanks%20are%20due%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CThanks%20is%20due%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think this needs more context to say definitively which should be used. 'An **individual thanks is due** to Dr. Holt' is just one example I came across where "thanks" can be used in the phrase and not have the same sense that we would expect. I think this is a little trickier question for a learner than it appears at first blush.

Comment: @ColleenV: Oh, come on! You might as well say ***a** formal expression of thanks*, or ***a** carefully-worded letter of thanks* justify OP's singular. You can force whatever plurality you want on a noun fragment forming part of a longer multi-word noun phrase.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I know - I'm just saying I think this is off-topic because it doesn't have enough context and not because its general reference. I try to think of ways that someone unfamiliar with the language might run into a phrase that doesn't conform with the most common usage, especially after that last go-round with "a dumbest girl".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, the word *thanks* is considered to be plural, so we would say "thanks are due," not "thanks is due".

That said, this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Thanks+are+due%2CThanks+is+due&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) provided  shows a modest number of hits for *thanks is due.* So what's going on there?

Fact is, the word *thanks* is a little flexible, and can be used in various ways that would make it hard to provide a black-and-white answer to this question.

For example, if we put the indefinite article in front of *thanks,* we notice that *"a thanks"* is an informal way of saying *"a thank-you"*, particularly when there is an adjective between them. So, neither of these would be considered incorrect:

> A special **thanks is** due to FumbleFingers, who pointed out that Ngrams can be misleading.
>   A huge **thanks is** reserved for Linda and Penelope.

Moreover, the word *thanks* may be the object in a prepositional phrase, just before a verb. In those cases, the verb would agree with the subject of the sentence, not the object in the prepositional phrase. For example:

> After all the work he has done for us, I think a token of **thanks is** due to Mr. Smith.
>   She worked her fingers to the bone; a word of **thanks is** due here.
>   A warm expression of **thanks is** due to those on both sides of the Atlantic.

<sup>(That last one is quoted from the book entitled *Europe and America: The Prospects for Partnership* by John Peterson, 1996)</sup>

I managed to find a few instances where neither one of these were true, like this one:

> Thanks is due to my parents, Charles and Susan, for their encouragement, help, and support.

Personally, I think "thanks are due" would have read better here, but this author may have deliberately opted to treat the word *thanks* as a mass noun – which is probably justifiable. After all, it's not like I can give you "one thank" (or, if I'm especially grateful, "two thanks").

Comment: Thanks for the thanks! :) I must admit it doesn't sit all that well with me though, being a usage that [never caught on until well after I'd learned what to expect...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=A+special+thanks+is&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CA%20special%20thanks%20is%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: ...and it's still [way outnumbered](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=A+special+thanks+is%2CSpecial+thanks+are&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CA%20special%20thanks%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CSpecial%20thanks%20are%3B%2Cc0) by the (to me, at least) far more natural *Special thanks **are** due...* (or the slightly less formal ***A** special **thank you is** due...*)

Comment: A reference or two would be appropriate. [CD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/thanks), [OLD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/thanks_2),  [Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/thanks), [Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/thanks), [AHD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/thanks) and [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/thanks) specify plural agreement,

Answer (score -2):

In your sentence "thanks" is a noun, and dictionaries don't seem to provide the information about whether or not that's a plural. But considering "thank" is also a word, we can only assume.

The better sentence to use is

> Thanks are due

Which is pretty clear from [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=thanks%20are%2C%20thanks%20is&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthanks%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthanks%20is%3B%2Cc0).
Though, neither are incorrect.

Comment: Your NGram link is misleading. Almost every entry for ***thanks is*** will be an "accidental collocation", and the few that aren't will all be typos, non-native speakers, etc.

Comment: You're right. "Thanks is" is not correct. "Thanks" is plural of "thank"